# How not to adjust the line space automatically?

Tags: line-spacing

My latex document always adjusts the line space if there are not enough lines to fill in the whole page, making the view pretty weird. But I cannot figure out what causes it.

[image]

Environment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\lstset{language=Python}

%\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\CompileMatrices
%\usepackage{coordsys}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[prop]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{claim}[prop]{Claim}
\newtheorem{alg}[prop]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{cor}[prop]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{example}[prop]{Example}

\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{alg*}{Algorithm}
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{bonus}{Bonus Question}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rmk}[prop]{Remark}
\newtheorem*{rmk*}{Remark}
\newtheorem{notation}[prop]{Notation}
\newtheorem*{notation*}{Notation}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[prop]{Definition}

\newcommand{\GL}{\mathrm{GL}}
\newcommand{\SL}{\mathrm{SL}}

\newcommand{\N}{\mybf{N}}

\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}

\providecommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}
\providecommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\newcommand{\ON}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-.25in} \addtolength{\textwidth}{.5in}


%%% START HERE

\title{title}
 \author{name}
 \address{uni}
\date{\today}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get.

Comment: Use `\raggedbottom` in your preamble (the default is `\flushbottom`).

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Added as above.